# MethodNotAllowedHttpException with lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel's included AccessTokenFlow POST route

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0

This is my first Laravel project I'm on, and it has been a ton of fun so far.

I'm setting up an OAuth2 server. I have copied the code posted [here](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel) in to my routes file.

Via this block of code...

```
Route::post('oauth/access_token', function()
{
    return AuthorizationServer::performAccessTokenFlow();
});
```

I have tried doing http://local.server.com/oauth/access_token and a "MethodNotAllowedHttpException" error.

If there is any other information I could provide that would help you help me, please tell me!

Cheers

Comment: How does your request look,what kind of data are you sending? Are you sure you are doing a post not a get request?

Comment: Are you accessing by typing the url into your browser? Because your defined route accepts only a POST request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are typing `http://local.server.com/oauth/access_token` into the browser URL bar, then you are sending the request:

```
GET oauth/access_token
```

However, your route handles a `POST` request, and since there is no `GET` route defined, Laravel is responding with `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

In order to properly test your route, you will need to send a `POST` request.